# Office 365 integration having load balancer

Tags: php, office365, load-balancing

I am trying to connect my application to Office 365 which works fine in my localhost. But as soon as I put this up in my acceptance server, it fails because it runs on two legs that are `http://` themselves with a load balancer on top that has `https://`. Since the actual request on my acceptance server goes from the `http` legs and not the `https` load balancer and Microsoft graph API does not allow any `http` requests it is creating this problem.

I am looking for a workaround for this. Also, is there a way to get the load balancer url using PHP? I mean `"http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"` works fine, but returns the server leg url (which is a `http`) and not the actual load balancer url (that is `https`)

I hope to have explained my problem clearly. Looking for any lead.

Thanks

Comment: I think it needs a bit of clarification. You are looking to call Microsoft Graph using some access token? You've registered your domain (localhost + load balancer URL) When you want to make requests to Graph, you are getting URLs of the leaf server nodes and not the load balancer URL? Is that the problem? Are you making requests from JavaScript (which would pass some headers automatically) or your server?

Comment: Mavi, I have MS Graph all set to receive O365 data. I have registered both my local domain (http://localhost/proj) and my acceptance domain (https://my-acc-domain.com) there. So requests should go from both. It works fine for my local environment. But the problem appears in ACC, since Graph does not allow request from any http server if it is not a localhost. My ACC has a https, but it is in the load balancer. When the request goes from my ACC, the `redirectUri` parameter takes the default host name which is the leg name of the server. The legs are not https,hence the requests are not accepted

Comment: There's definitely some misconfiguration here. How is your load balancer URL different from your acceptance server URL? Why are you automatically assigning the redirect URI - but not manually set it to be the top level domain, instead of your legs? What are these legs / are these leaf servers which the load balancer distributes the requests to?

Comment: Yes Mavi, exactly, they are leaf servers. I am not sure why by default printing my domain returns these leaf server host names.